# I can not do Vue Select component for Vue cli installation work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, v-select

I have install Vue Select component on my Vue cli application but the select behaviour is like a normal v-select.
I had installed using its official documentation. https://vue-select.org/

Here is the installation

```
npm install vue-select

Then, import and register the component:

import Vue from 'vue'
import vSelect from 'vue-select'

Vue.component('v-select', vSelect)
The component itself does not include any CSS. You'll need to include it separately:

import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
Alternatively, you can import the scss for complete control of the component styles:

@import "vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss";
```

Here is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/axios'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import vSelect from "vue-select";
 
Vue.component("v-select", vSelect);
import 'vue-select/dist/vue-select.css';
import "vue-select/src/scss/vue-select.scss";

import '@/components';
import '@/assets/scss/main.scss';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
enter code here
```

Here is how I use the component

```
<v-select :options="['Canada', 'United States']"></v-select>
```

but my v-select is the basic select for vue and vuetify, even, no items are load.
[image]

I really appreciate your help it is my first reactive application so, many things are great and different to traditional html, js, css proyects.

Comment: where is it getting "No data available" from?

Comment: Use :items not :options

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I had already changed :options for :items and yea the items are showing but the select doesn't have the jquery chosen behaviour. With a text input for searching items in select.

Answer (score 0):

There is no :options for v-select props.
You must use ":items".

`<v-select :items="['Canada', 'United States']"></v-select>`

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-select/#props

See the examples and API.

As long as you need to learn something, you must read official document first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yeah it is right there is not :options prop. I have changed :options for :items and items are showing but the select is a basic select I need a jquery chosen kind select. In the official documentation of the component use :options thats why I have used it. But I don't have the chosen behavihour.

Comment: Are you using jquery and vuetify?
I think it's not good choice for compability.
Just use vue and vuetify. It is enough for implementing what you want.

Comment: Hi Sam. No, I'm not using jquery and vuetify I only want the behaviour of jquery chosen plugin for selects but with a Vue component. As I said I follow all instructions of this component https://vue-select.org/ but not working. Select still de default vuetify select.

Comment: Check your env is OK.
[v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#custom-text-and-value)

And reference the sample code in official site.
Run this in your env.
This minimal code should work.

If there is problem, let me know error message in your console.
[How to check browser console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Comment: OMG Sam I was reading and vuetify has the component that I need. is v-autocomplete https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/ is a list that use a filter for searching througth the items of list. I was wondering why vuetify doesn't have some that is for better user experience and it has a lot of options.... Vuetify is great. Thank you so much for time and  I didn't know about browser console.  :)

Comment: v-autocomplete is great.
I also usually use it when I need filter.
You can cutomize filter system and items and values.
It would be great.
Have a nice coding.